# HTTP POST multipart with named file

Tags: http, elixir, phoenix-framework

I need to send a (multipart) HTTP request which contains a file which is named. This seems to be harder to achieve than I imagined... I've tried to figure out a way to do it with HTTPoison, [but I can't get it to use a name other than "file"](https://github.com/edgurgel/httpoison/issues/89). I've tried using Hackney directly, [but there doesn't appear to be an option](https://github.com/benoitc/hackney/blob/master/doc/hackney.md#request5), and there definitely isn't a test on either of these which shows this functionality. I've also had a look at ibrowse and HTTPotion but can't find anything which seems useful (my Erlang is very limited, mind you). [Here is an example](https://github.com/taf2/curb#http-post-file-upload) of what I want to do, with the Ruby library Curb (note the Curl::PostField.file takes a name and a file path).

Is this such a strange thing to do? Or am I missing something obvious here... Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In case anyone in the future encounters this problem, here's the solution:

```
HTTPoison.start
request = HTTPoison.post!(url, {:multipart, [{:file, "path/to/file", { ["form-data"], [name: "\"photo\"", filename: "\"/path/to/file\""]},[]}]}, headers, options)
```

Note the extra escaped quotes.

Comment: Pay attention to the double quotation marks escapes for name and filename, they are kind of mandatory, instead HTTPoison wont properly forge the request.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it working with

```
HTTPoison.post!(url, {:multipart, [{"name", "value"}, {:file, path_to_file}]})
```

with some help from this [Github issue](https://github.com/edgurgel/httpoison/issues/47)