# Making a HTTPoison POST multipart request with more data other than the file

Tags: http, elixir, multipart, httpoison

I'm trying to build a function to send a file through a POST request in multipart format, using *[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33557133/http-post-multipart-with-named-file)* as guide, but HTTPoison keeps giving me two errors no matter what changes I make to the form. They are all

```
HTTPoison.post("https://api.telegram.org/myCredentials", {:multipart, form}, headers)
```

and the three versions of my form and the errors are the following (whether I use headers or not):

1st and 2nd Version (same error for both):

```
form = [{"photo", [{"name", "myphoto.jpg"}, {:file, "files/aphoto.jpg"}]}, {"chat_id", 237799110}]
-----
form = [photo: [{"name", "myphoto.jpg"}, {:file, "files/aphoto.jpg"}], chat_id: 237799110]
```

Which give me this error:

```
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in anonymous fn/2 in :hackney_multipart.len_mp_stream/2
      (hackney) c:/Users/venta/projects/elixir/wrapper/deps/hackney/src/hackney_multipart.erl:159: anonymous fn({"photo", [{"name", "myphoto.jpg"}, {:file, "files/aphoto.jpg"}]}, 0) in :hackney_multipart.len_mp_stream/2
       (stdlib) lists.erl:1263: :lists.foldl/3
      (hackney) c:/Users/venta/projects/elixir/wrapper/deps/hackney/src/hackney_multipart.erl:159: :hackney_multipart.len_mp_stream/2
      (hackney) c:/Users/venta/projects/elixir/wrapper/deps/hackney/src/hackney_request.erl:319: :hackney_request.handle_body/4
      (hackney) c:/Users/venta/projects/elixir/wrapper/deps/hackney/src/hackney_request.erl:81: :hackney_request.perform/2
      (hackney) c:/Users/venta/projects/elixir/wrapper/deps/hackney/src/hackney.erl:373: :hackney.send_request/2
    (httpoison) lib/httpoison/base.ex:432: HTTPoison.Base.request/9
```

And the third version:

```
form = [chat_id: 237799110, photo: [{"name", "myphoto.jpg"}, {:file, "files/aphoto.jpg"}]]
```

Which gives me the following error:

```
** (ArgumentError) argument error
              :erlang.byte_size(:chat_id)
    (hackney) c:/Users/venta/projects/elixir/wrapper/deps/hackney/src/hackney_multipart.erl:255: :hackney_multipart.mp_data_header/2
    (hackney) c:/Users/venta/projects/elixir/wrapper/deps/hackney/src/hackney_multipart.erl:180: anonymous fn/3 in :hackney_multipart.len_mp_stream/2
     (stdlib) lists.erl:1263: :lists.foldl/3
    (hackney) c:/Users/venta/projects/elixir/wrapper/deps/hackney/src/hackney_multipart.erl:159: :hackney_multipart.len_mp_stream/2
    (hackney) c:/Users/venta/projects/elixir/wrapper/deps/hackney/src/hackney_request.erl:319: :hackney_request.handle_body/4
    (hackney) c:/Users/venta/projects/elixir/wrapper/deps/hackney/src/hackney_request.erl:81: :hackney_request.perform/2
    (hackney) c:/Users/venta/projects/elixir/wrapper/deps/hackney/src/hackney.erl:373: :hackney.send_request/2
```

I find invariable misfortune in the series of events that impose such obstacles over a multipart POST request, so I would like to listen to an opinion about the possible causes that lead to them.

Now, I'd be more than happy to write my own request from scratch following [*this*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913626/what-should-a-multipart-http-request-with-multiple-files-look-like) format, but I'm forcing myself to use Elixir and its resources to eventually learn it after a few mishaps like this.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the documentation for `HTTPoison.post/3`.  The 2nd argument is a `body` type which if you look in the docs for that type spec you will find:

```
body :: binary | {:form, [{atom, any}]} | {:file, binary}
```

Your 2nd argument doesn't match that typespec.  You are sending `{:multipart, form}`.

This [Github Issue](https://github.com/edgurgel/httpoison/issues/47) on HTTPoison does seem to suggest you can use `{:multipart, []}` even though it doesn't match the documented spec, and [an example test case for multipart is here](https://github.com/edgurgel/httpoison/commit/af3931f9c00f4d520697243fbac4c1d7125418ee).

Based on your example, maybe something like:

`form = [{:file, "files/aphoto.jpg"}, {"name", "myphoto.jpg"}, {"chat_id", 237799110}]`

Comment: The problem with the form as you put it is that Telegram api requires that the file be sent within the "photo" object. Like {chat_id: destination, photo: multipart/form-data file, other parameters to modify the message sent to the api}. What do you suggest for this?

Comment: I just remembered, I have been able to send a request like this: `HTTPoison.post! url, {:form, [some: "data"]}`, which has been successfully received as form by HTTPbin

Comment: As you can see [here](https://github.com/edgurgel/httpoison/blob/master/lib/httpoison/base.ex#L160), any request that the code makes cannot have two or more arguments for `{:body, content}`, `{:form, content}`, etc., since the third argument will be processed as headers. Edit: However, it seems that multipart is not mentioned at all there. possibilities are raw binary, char list or iotlist or tuple `:form`, `:file` or `:stream`